# HTML text being reformatted on mobile view based on number of characters

Tags: html

I have some html which is having its font size scaled up or down based on whether it has over or under a certain number of characters in the body. Here it is:

```
<html><head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
        Donec bibendum nunc leo, quis placerat nisl euismod ac. 
        Aenean et nisi malesuada malesuada malesuada malesuada
        malesuada malesuada malesuada malesuada malesuada 
        </div>
</body></html>
```

If you open this in chrome, and switch to mobile view, the text is very small. Here is an image in case it appears different for you: https://i.ibb.co/R6Fbmtp/small.png

However, if you add a single character to the text and view it again, suddenly the text is much larger and easier to read, another image: https://i.ibb.co/5cN1Sgb/large.png

Can anyone explain why this might be happening? It's not even necessary to apply any styling or breakpoints to get this to occur.

Comment: Your code works for me in the usual way. I'm using chrome. Are you using css frameworks?

Comment: The original code I noticed this in was Vue, but I kept removing things to produce a minimal reproducible example, and the code I used above is able to produce the effect in just a plain html file with no extra processing/imports. If you try adding or removing a few extra lines (depending on whether you see the font size smaller or larger), does the formatting change?

Comment: As an update to this, I've tested on multiple devices using both chrome and edge, and there is always a breakpoint after which text is rendered correctly. Possibly a bug in the way chrome/edge mobile display interprets html if it's not an intended consequence of something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone experiencing this same problem, the solution is that the above html does not contain a tag which sets the viewport properties, as described here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp

The possibility of a breakpoint in content length having an impact on how elements are scaled seems irrelevant, now, because all websites should have the above tag (if they will ever be viewed on mobile).